# Find Specific Function in Huge source code, any trick using debugger etc

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, debugging, find

I am playing with NotePad++ Open source code, What i am currently doing is, finding function that convert a string to a click-able URL.

[image]

This is huge code and not easy to find this function manually. Is there any trick to find its function **using Visual Studio Debugger**. I believe there should be some trick to find those function using debuggers. Like Start debugging when i click on that URL link and debugger directly go to that function.

Hope you understand what i mean...

Comment: in NotePad++ there is an option called "Find In Files", here, you can specify the folder location and extension of files (*.h, *.cpp etc) you want to search

Comment: i know that good hint already, but its not my solution, its more complex